# BERTopic Visualization

Tags: visualization, bert, topic-model

I new to `topic modeling` and I'm trying to use `BERTopic` inside of `PyCharm`. I'm struggling to get any type of visualization to work inside of `PyCharm` with `BERTopic`.

Here is my current code:

```
import pickle
from umap import UMAP
from hdbscan import HDBSCAN
from bertopic import BERTopic
from sent2vec.vectorizer import Vectorizer
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer


# 6000 articles about cryptocurrencies
with open('all_articles', 'rb') as file_in:
    random_articles = pickle.load(file_in)

embedding_model = SentenceTransformer('all-MiniLM-L6-v2')
umap_model = UMAP(n_neighbors=3, 
                  n_components=3, 
                  min_dist=0.05)

hdbscan_model = HDBSCAN(min_cluster_size=80, 
                        min_samples=40,
                        gen_min_span_tree=True,
                        prediction_data=True)

vectorizer_model = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(1, 2), 
                                   stop_words='english')

model = BERTopic(
    umap_model=umap_model,
    hdbscan_model=hdbscan_model,
    embedding_model=embedding_model,
    vectorizer_model=vectorizer_model,
    top_n_words=5,
    language='english',
    calculate_probabilities=True,
    verbose=True
)
topics, probs = model.fit_transform(random_articles)

# this produces nothing
model.visualize_topics(top_n_topics=5)
```

I found this [issue](https://github.com/MaartenGr/BERTopic/issues/339) on visualization not working within `PyCharm` with `BERTopic`.  This issue wasn't useful in solving my issue.

How do I get something to visualize inside of `PyCharm`?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried replacing your last line with the following?

```
fig = model.visualize_topics(top_n_topics=5)
fig.show()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).